# NoClassDefFoundError for BasicLogger Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jar, struts

I am trying to integrate **Hibernate** with **Struts 2**. I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` for `BasicLogger`. Here is the trace:

```
exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception

root cause 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2959)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1212)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1692)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:86)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.createAndTestSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:264)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:227)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.getNewSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:155)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:100)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.getHibernateSessionFromFactory(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:379)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.injectHibernateCoreSessionByAnnotation(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:454)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.injectHibernateCoreSessionByAnnotation(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:470)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.intercept(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)



root cause 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1722)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2959)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1212)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1692)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:86)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.createAndTestSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:264)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:227)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.getNewSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:155)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:100)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.getHibernateSessionFromFactory(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:379)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.injectHibernateCoreSessionByAnnotation(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:454)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.injectHibernateCoreSessionByAnnotation(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:470)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.intercept(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
```

What jars could I be missing? Here is my list of jars for logging:

- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- slf4j-log4j-1.2.17.jar

I also have javassist and dom4j. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need `jboss-logging.jar` to provide `org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger`

Comment: Thank you. However, which version would I need? I'm now getting a NoClassDefFoundError for org/jboss/logging/DelegatingBasicLogger.

Comment: It depends on many factors, servlet container, other dependencies, ... I will try first with las version, and if it fails, downgrade. Maven is a useful tool, you could think it.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this exception message while setting up Hibernate I had to download a bunch of libraries before eventually making it work. After solving one problem, another class would not be found, so I would simply copy paste into google the packet name of the class for which I got the ClassNotFoundException or NoClassDefFoundError, I would download the jar and put it into the project strucure. I repeated this process several times over until the program was finally running correctly. Here are the links to all the websites from which I downloaded jar libraries after reading this exception message and before I made the program work correctly:

```
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/source-code

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/jakarta.transaction

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.fasterxml/classmate

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/net.bytebuddy

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/jakarta.xml.bind

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations

https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream
```